# Django passing querysets between pages

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have a view which does a pretty heavy query on three separate databases and outputs the count of each query into a template. From the the user can go to one of the three results and get the detailed results. I  don't want to repeat myself in my views and I want to maximize performance, so my question is what is the best way to achieve this result?

Can I pass a queryset to another page (get or post)?
Should I save the queryset in a session (I am not currently using session for this project as it is fully public)
Or is there a better way?

I know this is not a highly specific question, but I would appreciate any advice on this (I'm guessing - not uncommon) situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the *result* of the querysets to the session. When I say to save the results, what I mean is to run `list()` on it to execute them, and then store the resulting list in `request.session`.

Comment: What are the advantages of saving the results as a list, rather than simply saving the queryset directly? In this case, since only the count is considered in the first view, wouldn't the queryset execute a different query to actually get the objects, which could be delayed until the chosen detailed results page is loaded?

Answer (score 3):

From my experience, I think saving your result on `session` is a good and simple solution.

Answer (score 1):

sounds like you want to have a look at [caching](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/)